# Check window size always (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, size

i want to check if the browser has a secific pixel size. This is my try:

```
var height = $(".size_fullscreen").height();
var width = $(".size_fullscreen").width();
if (height == 1024 && width == 768) {
    alert("please flip");
}
```

That worked for me at first, but now i want to check this script always. So if the size gets changed there should popup something like "thank you" or so.

I think there is the document ready function in jquery, but i didn't get a solution with it.

Can anybody help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 $document.ready(function(){

    /** Functions to call on Window Resize**/
    var ResizeTimer;

    $(window).on("resize", function(){
        clearTimeout(ResizeTimer);
        ResizeTimer = setTimeout(function(){

        // Add your functions here
        var wH = $(".size_fullscreen").height();
        var wW = $(".size_fullscreen").width();
          if (wH == 1024 && wW == 768) {
                 alert("please flip");
          }

       // wait for 200ms between each resize event
        },200); 
    });
    // Call your function on DOM ready / Trigger resize
    $(window).trigger('resize');

});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check the script that you wrote always then just put it in the window resize event.

Example:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
 var height = $(window).height();
 var width = $(window).width();
if (height == 1024 && width == 768) {
    alert("please flip");
}

});
```